# how to multiply variable to each element of a column in database

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to add a column to a collection by multiplying the 0.9 to existing database column recycling. but I get a run time error.
I tried to multiply 0.9 direction in the function but it is showing error, so I created the class and multiplied it there yet no use. what could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is telling you what the problem is: your database query is using GROUP BY in an invalid way.

It doesn't make sense to group by one column and then select other columns (you've selected all columns in your case); what values would they contain, since you haven't grouped by them as well (and get one row returned per group)? You either have to group by all the columns you're selecting for, and/or use aggregates such as SUM for the non-grouped columns.

Perhaps you meant to ORDER BY that column (`orderBy(dt.recycling.asc())` if ascending order in QueryDSL format), or to select all rows with a particular value of that column (`where(dt.recycling.eq(55))` for example)?